# Structured trace logging of large objects through ILogger in ApplicationInsights

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, ilogger

We are attempting to log large data objects through `ILogger.Log`, but are experiencing trimming of the data we send to ApplicationInsights. The data objects we are trying to log are request/response from an integration source for diagnostic purposes during development. Needless to say, the request/response can get quite large.

Our first attempt was to just read the content out of the request/response as a string and send it to ApplicationInsights through `ILogger.Log`. However, we quickly realized that the content got trimmed. Upon further investigation, we discovered ApplicationInsights property value string length limit of 8192 bytes (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/application-insights-limits.md).

Our next attempt was to deserialize and send the request/response as objects (JToken) to ApplicationiInsights through `ILogger.Log`. Our hope was that ApplicationInsightsLoggingProvider would log objects in a more structured manner and thereby altogether skipping the property value string length limit of 8192 bytes. However, this unfortunately made matters worse. The request/response was still being logged as string in ApplicationInsights, but now in a format that took two bytes per character instead of one. Essentially cutting our logging capabilities in half.

The attached code is our current implementation. We are logging the request/response through a `DelegatingHandler`. It is inserted into `HttpClient`s outgoing pipeline right after ASPs `LogicalHandler` through a custom `IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter`. Our `DelegatingHandler` utelizes `LoggerMessage` pattern (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/loggermessage?view=aspnetcore-3.0), and will only log when the log level is set to trace. The current implementation is version two, where we attempt to deserialize the request/response extracted JSON string into a JToken (line 107) and send it to ApplicationInsights through `ILogger.Log`. Should the deserialization fail, it would fall back to our version one equivalent implementation, where the raw string would be sent to `ILogger.Log`.

We are using the ApplicationInsightsLoggingProvider from `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` version `2.8.2`.

So the question becomes: How can we log large objects to ApplicationInsights through ILogger, preferably in a structured format so we can query it with kusto?

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Shared.Extensions.IntegrationPolicies
{
    public class CustomLoggingFilter : IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter
    {
        private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

        public CustomLoggingFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _loggerFactory = loggerFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
        }

        public Action<HttpMessageHandlerBuilder> Configure(Action<HttpMessageHandlerBuilder> next)
        {
            if (next == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
            }

            return builder =>
            {
                next(builder);
                var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger($"System.Net.Http.HttpClient.{builder.Name}.CustomLogger");
                builder.AdditionalHandlers.Insert(1, new CustomLoggingHandler(logger));
            };
        }
    }

    internal class CustomLoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public CustomLoggingHandler(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
            }

            await Log.LogRequest(_logger, request);
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            await Log.LogResponse(_logger, response);
            return response;
        }

        private static class Log
        {
            private static readonly LogLevel LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;

            private static readonly Action<ILogger, HttpMethod, Uri, object, Exception> LogRequestAction =
                LoggerMessage.Define<HttpMethod, Uri, object>(
                    LogLevel,
                    EventIds.PipelineStart,
                    $"Start processing HTTP request {{HttpMethod}} {{Uri}}{Environment.NewLine}{{Body}}");

            private static readonly Action<ILogger, HttpStatusCode, object, Exception> LogResponseAction =
                LoggerMessage.Define<HttpStatusCode, object>(
                    LogLevel,
                    EventIds.PipelineEnd,
                    $"End processing HTTP request - {{StatusCode}}{Environment.NewLine}{{Body}}");

            public static async Task LogRequest(ILogger logger, HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                if (!logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel))
                {
                    return;
                }

                var content = await GetContent(request.Content);
                LogRequestAction(logger, request.Method, request.RequestUri, content, null);
            }

            public static async Task LogResponse(ILogger logger, HttpResponseMessage response)
            {
                if (!logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel))
                {
                    return;
                }

                var content = await GetContent(response.Content);
                LogResponseAction(logger, response.StatusCode, content, null);
            }

            private static async Task<object> GetContent(HttpContent content)
            {
                if (content == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                await content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();
                var contentAsString = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return TryParseJson<object>(contentAsString, out var contentAsObject) 
                    ? contentAsObject 
                    : contentAsString;
            }

            private static bool TryParseJson<T>(string value, out T result)
            {
                var success = true;
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    Error = (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        success = false; 
                        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                    }
                };
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value, settings);
                return success;
            }

            private static class EventIds
            {
                public static readonly EventId PipelineStart = new EventId(100, "RequestPipelineStart");
                public static readonly EventId PipelineEnd = new EventId(101, "RequestPipelineEnd");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to run Kusto queries on body content? Or the goal is to find request of interest and then be able to explore/reconstruct body content? If the latter then you might consider two options: 1) use raw AI SDK to track requests and then split body into multiple custom dimensions (8192 is a limit per dimension). There is still a limit on overall message but it is bigger. 2) put some correlation field into request and then save body either completely independently or split and log it to Application Insights through different telemetry items (for instance, though custom events).

Comment: @ZakiMa thanks for your suggestion and quick feedback! :D To run Kusto queries against the body would be preferable, but not needed. Using `TelemetryClient` directly as you suggest would enable us to solve the issue we are having with AI. The thought have crossed my mind. However, unfortunately it defeats the purpose of "program to an abstraction", which in my eyes makes it a workaround. I am wondering if there is a specific way to send data through `ApplicationInsightsLoggingProvider` so that the data not be interpreted as a string, but rather as a dictionary.

Comment: no, as the underlying storage treats customDimensions as a dictionary of string:string, (and customMeasurements as string:double).  there's no other levels/layers of abstraction/interpretation.  if you can't fit things into custom dimensions, there's also cases we've seen (or done) where the long content gets sent as a trace message (that string is allowed to be huge), and ensure that other fields like operation_Id (or other common custom properties like a clientRequestId in customDimensions) are set so that the telemetry can be found together in queries